# How to use 3rd variable in BASH for loop?

Tags: bash, for

I want to parse data of particular columns from several files(aprilPlate.txt, mayPlate.txt, junePlate.txt, julyPlate.txt, augustPlate.txt) using For loop.

The data of input files (aprilPlate.txt, mayPlate.txt, junePlate.txt, julyPlate.txt, augustPlate.txt) look like:

```
Incl    Cal Ps  Name    Q   Con Std Status
True    255 A1  Sample 1    35.86       0   
True    255 A2  Sample 2    36.06       0   
True    255 A3  Sample 3    17.45       0   
True    255 A4  Sample 4    17.56       0   
True    255 A5  Sample 5    17.55       0   
True    255 A6  Sample 6    40.00       0   
True    255 A7  Sample 7    36.38       0   
True    255 A8  Sample 8    27.98       0   
True    255 A9  Sample 9    27.95       0   
True    255 A10 Sample 10   28.19       0   
True    255 A11 Sample 11   36.93       0   
True    255 A12 Sample 12   37.74       0   
True    255 A13 Sample 13   17.88       0   
True    255 A14 Sample 14   17.82       0   
True    255 A15 Sample 15   17.90       0   
.
.
.
```

By using FOR loop, I able to get the task done. However, in order to get desire data from all files, I have to modify the file name in the script (below) manually.

```
#!/bin/bash

# parse the data of desire columns from target file
# rename the column name 
# redirect the stdoutput to a text file

for z in A B; 
  do for i in 3 4 5 13 14 15; 
    do grep $z$i aprilPlate.txt | 
       awk -F "\t" '{print $3 "\t" $5}' | 
       sed -e 's/A[3-5]/st_SWC/g;s/A[1][0-9]/st_SWD/g;s/B[3-5]/st_TZC/g;s/B[1][0-9]/st_TZD/g;' >> stone.txt; 
  done;
done

for z in E F; 
  do for i in 8 9 10 18 19 20;
    do grep $z$i aprilPlate.txt | 
       awk -F "\t" '{print $3 "\t" $5}' | 
       sed -e 's/E[8-9]\|E[1][0]/su_SWC/g;s/E[1][0-9]\|E[2][0]/su_SWD/g;s/F[8-9]\|F[1][0]/su_TZC/g;s/F[1][0-9]\|F[2][0]/su_TZD/g;' >> suy.txt;
  done;
done

paste -d'\t' stone.txt suy.txt >> aprilPlate.data.txt
```

- My apologies, I made a mistake in my previous coding. The correction was done.

The output of parsed data file should looks like:

```
st_SWC  17.45   su_SWC  28.85
st_SWC  17.56   su_SWC  28.79
st_SWC  17.55   su_SWC  28.82
st_SWD  17.88   su_SWD  29.24
st_SWD  17.82   su_SWD  29.18
st_SWD  17.90   su_SWD  29.23
st_TZC  18.06   su_TZC  25.99
st_TZC  18.09   su_TZC  25.98
st_TZC  18.13   su_TZC  26.02
st_TZD  17.75   su_TZD  25.00
st_TZD  17.70   su_TZD  25.01
st_TZD  17.69   su_TZD  24.98
```

**I would like to ask, is there anyway I can have the files as 3rd variable in the script? Other solutions are welcome.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like will help you

```
for file in aprilPlate.txt  mayPlate.txt  junePlate.txt  julyPlate.txt  augustPlate.txt;
do
for z in A B; 
  do for i in 3 4 5 13 14 15; 
    do grep $z$i $file | 
       awk -F "\t" '{print $3 "\t" $5}' | 
       sed -e 's/A[3-5]/SWC/g;s/A[1][0-9]/SWD/g;s/B[3-5]/TZC/g;s/B[1][0-9]/TZD/g;' >> stone.txt; 
  done;
done
<snip>
done
```

Comment: Of course w/o commas between filenames (my mistake, edited)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do since you have no input or output examples, but the following should work.

```
#!/bin/bash
awksrc='BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
{ gsub(/A[345]|E[89]|E10/, "SWC");
  gsub(/A1[0-9]|E1[1-9]|E20/, "SWD");
  gsub(/B[345]|F[89]|F10/, "TZC");
  gsub(/B1[0-9]|F1[1-9]|F20/, "TZD");
}
/SW[CD]{print $3, $5 >"stone.txt"}
/TZ[CD]{print $3, $5 >"suy.txt"}'
for file in aprilPlate.txt mayPlate.txt junePlate.txt julyPlate.txt ...
do
    awk "$awkscr" $file >/dev/null
    paste -d'\t' stone.txt suy.txt >> ${file%.txt}.data.txt
done
```

The `${file%.txt}` gets the base name, without the extension to be able to add the `.data.txt` extension.

This reduces the number of shell loops to just one, and processes each file once.  The output of the `awk` script is unneeded since the files are getting written to inside it.

Again, without example input, it's hard to say if this is correct for your purposes.

Comment: I have the input and output examples included in my question now. Thanks for your suggestion.